# Issue with editing edittext in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-edittext, expandablelistadapter

I have 3 group containing 3 child which has EditText , when I click on EditText the software keyboard pop's out, at that time the expandable list is redrawn

When the I am done with text editing , software keypad is closed at that time I need to store the value of EditText present in the all 3 child of all 3 group, since on the redraw of list the edited values are not got stored.

Any suggestion for using EditText in ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is the best solution, but what I did is to use another list to store the values of each EditText, let me know if you find something better

Comment: I have to write the click listener again for same.